# Is it possible to embed the HTML output of a Zeppelin Notebook so that the output can be looked at when the server hosting the Notebook isn't active?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

I have a Zeppelin Notebook producing interactive graphs. I don't want to have to host the notebook indefinitely but I want to have that interactive output appear on another website. I understand that I can "link to this paragraph" and then embed the output in an iframe, but that requires the notebook to be running indefinitely. Is there a way to just download the HTML output?

Comment: Unfortuanly no, but what you can do is save the output into a CSV file a render it per day in D3js or similar.

Comment: From my experience, in order that embedded iframe to work, you need also an user authenticated in zeppelin. Anonymous access to the graphs works, if and only if the security is disabled. This information not written in the documentation https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/publish.html

Answer (score 3):

One way will be do it similar as Zeppelin do. Zeppelin use nvd3 for charts. And nvd3 use D3, the essence is generate SVG from data. Zeppelin add others js/css for styling and interactive.

In order to create a graph, you can.

- Right click the graph, choose Inspect. Copy the svg element
- Create a simple web page, put the svg element in the html body
- Add link for nvd3 js and css. you can either using Bower or link to CDN directly

The chart so far looks the same, but does not have interactive function. Those features can be added if you spend a bit more time.

I create a jsfiddle, Standalone Zeppelin Chart Without Zeppelin `rockiey/x5Lyd204`

Comment: This is excellent Rockie. I was struggling with a problem (exposing the paragraph link without security).  I am able to use this technique as a workaround.